# Amazon Relational Database service connection refused error- PHP Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, laravel-5.3

i am trying to connect the database in PHP-Laravel but I getting error connection refused.

Though database is connected when I run any query it shows me this message.

[image]

Is there a way around to fix this? what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Have you provided proper host name, username and password?

Comment: @PankajMakwana I have provided a proper username, password and database name.

Comment: Have you tried connecting with core PHP not with laravel?

Comment: @PankajMakwana i have followed all these steps http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/php-laravel-tutorial.html#php-laravel-tutorial-database . it shows Database is connected when i run the migrations it throughs this error.

Comment: Check below post may this help you.
https://serverfault.com/questions/263260/why-cant-i-connect-to-amazon-rds-after-setting-it-up